# Sanity Check, connecting 3 phase solar inverter with only 3 wires Update

Tags: inverter, three-phase

Here is an 3nd update to my post.

Reference to inverter data is removed since it apparently caused misinterpretation of this post.

This is not a question about a piece of equipment or how that piece of equipment operates.
It is a systems engineering question.
Specifically, what happens to single phase loads (over-voltage? under-voltage?) within some facility, if that facility is fed with 3-phase power with 3 wires only, i.e. there is no neutral from the power source?

Please read Case 2 of my diagram (below).

In terms of a specific question, do you agree that such a situation will result in over voltage and under voltage of single phase loads, depending upon other single phase loads on other phases.

Original post follows
a residential/commercial solar installer told me that they install 3 phase solar inverters, that connect to the end user building (residential, commercial) with 3 wires, i.e. the 3 hot phases.
This is a 208 VAC P to P and 120 VAC P to N application.

I do not understand how power can be supplied to single phase (120 VAC) loads without there being a neutral.

I have diagrammed this situation.
[image]

Case 1 is a single, 120 VAC load.
It is L3 to neutral (N) within the end user facility.
I do not see how current is expected to flow through this load.

Case 2 is 2 different loads.
One load is L3 to N, and the other load is L1 to N.
Here, current will flow phase-to phase and the voltage that appears across either load will depend upon the relative values of the 2 loads.

I can see how 3 wires only, will supply power to 2 phase loads and 3 phase loads, but not single phase loads without serious out-of-spec voltages, in the event of a sunny day (max solar output) and a power outage by the utility.

Question:
What happens to single phase loads (over-voltage? under-voltage?) within some facility, if that facility is fed with 3phase power with 3 wires only, i.e. there is no neutral from the power source?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but the two close votes that have been cast so far (visible to people with enough reputation) both chose the reason "Questions on the *use* of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics *design*." I am not sure if I agree with that, but this question does have several other issues--most notably, linking to an off-site image instead of inlining the image here is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Wow.. Thanks Hearth. I did not even know about the electronics design forum. Also, it's really hard .... a forum I post on for Linux (MX LINUX) will NOT let you put images on the post. You HAVE TO post them externally. So I was following that rule. Now I dont know what to do. But thanks all the same.

Comment: @xstack Please ask a specific question

Comment: I have edited post. I am asking for post to be reopened. It is not a post about a piece of equipment or how a piece of equipment operates. It is a systems engineering question. And it is VERY similar to other posts on EE forum. What happens to single phase loads in a facility, if it powered by 3 phase feed with only 3 wires. I believe it is a serious problem. I believe it is dangerous. Thank you.

Comment: Voltage Spike: I read your bio. Easily 90% of it describes me. Only difference probably is that I am a great deal older. Are to a spacecraft designer? I designed spacecraft and launch vehicles for military for 23 years, including Timation satellites that were the original Global Positioning System satellites.

Comment: (Aside: A *Neutral* terminal is mentioned as an option. (Not expecting it to come free.))

Comment: Well is this a grid-tied inverter, that only functions when it's connected to the grid (and sell the power back / offset your use)  or is the goal to operate your house/building without the grid sometimes?

Comment: Hi greybeard
Thank you.

Comment: Hi  tomnexus, Thank you for comment. Unfortunately power outages  occur. Some are 1-3 secs long. Some are 4 hours long. Also, the utility provider is fond of updating utility meters without any warning. They don't even knock on the door. They just yank the meter and put in a new one. Again, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 2):

For those not familiar with energy distribution networks this is indeed a question. Fortunately, there is more to it then only the inverter and the loads.

You omitted the MV/LV transformer of the utility in the diagrams. The current paths are incomplete.
The transformer performs the important role of **creating the neutral**.

It is theoretically possible to run inverters in Delta. Your utility may not want this. But it's possible.

The loads in your home are irrelevant as long as the transformer is present.

[image]

If the transformer is not present, there is no neutral. Or worse, a broken neutral. In that case the neutral will float, depending on the impedance of the loads. The loads are then basically an earth fault.

The phase voltages become asymmetric with respect to earth/neutral.
Damaging everything.
This is a common fault or mistake in installations unfortunately.
One easily prevented with proper procedures and detected with protection relays.

[image]

*And here you see where delta systems are sometimes used for. They tolerate **one** earth fault. With proper monitoring this can be used in critical systems (eg: ships) where a single fault will not cause a blackout. But a warning, then people can find and disconnect the bad equipment or cable.*

Comment: Hi Jeron3, Thank you for your reply and your detailed dwgs. Yes, of course, omitting the utility transformer is a big oversight. In the many reposts that I have had to do and the several times that others have edited my post (deleting paragraphs) it seems that the following 2 concerns are no longer present. 1] what happens in the case of a utility outage? 2] what happens of the utility decides to swap out a utility meter and there is no connection to transformer.? Thank you again for your insights and detailed diagrams and explanations.

Comment: @xstack pv inverters will not operate in island mode (anti-islanding) unless your entire system is designed to support this. You will need transfer switches and your own neutral bonding. A delta inverter will require a delta-star transformer to feed a star network.

Comment: Hi Jeroen3, Thank you for input.